# stdio.h in Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio-2015

I was wondering in which folder on my computer is stdio.h file placed. I have Windows 10, and Visual Studio 2015 (32 - bit) installed on my computer. Visual Studio includes tools for writing, compiling and executing C programs, so i think that it also must have stdio.h contained somewhere, am I right? I tried searching for stdio.h in folder C:\Program Files(x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC and all of it's subfolders, but with no success. I would very appreciate if anyone could give me some guidelines or a solution to this problem.

Thank you in advanced for your time and answers!

Comment: look in project properties - it shows you the include direcoty paths

Comment: I know I shouldn't ask, but why would you *want* to know this? Because your compiler complains about not finding it? (That's a different question.) Or because you want to look at it? (Don't. :-D )

Comment: its gonna be under the Microsoft SDKs folder somewhere

Comment: You can also open the header file in Visual Studio (follow the file). Then once inside the file VS should show you the exact location.

Comment: Into visual studio IDE, right click on `stdio.h`. It will show you an option like: Open document `"stdio.h"`

Comment: C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.10240.0\ucrt, usually.  Read up about the universal crt split in [this blog post](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/vcblog/2015/03/03/introducing-the-universal-crt/).

Comment: Thank you all for your answers! They all helped me, and I managed to find the file. It wasn't that hard, since Hans Passant gave me the exact location of it :D Thank you once again! @DevSolar I simply wanted to know where the headers like stdio are "physically" in Visual Studio. I knew where they where in Dev C++, and now, when I installed VS, I could not find them. So i had to ask :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"The headers, sources, and libraries are now distributed as part of a separate 
Universal CRT SDK. This SDK is included with Visual Studio; it is installed by 
default to C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10."