# Cannot open include file: 'stdio.h' - Visual Studio Community 2017 - C++ Error

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-studio-2017, stdio

I am trying to build a solution on Visual Studio Community 2017, but I keep getting the error "**Cannot open include file: 'stdio.h'** ".

I've read through several similar questions, but I still can't fix this problem. It looks like the **stdio.h** file is called in the **stdafx.h** file. Below are more details. Any suggestions?

**System details:**

- Windows 10
- Visual Studio Community 2017 v.15.2 (26430.6)
  -- Installed Desktop Development with C++  ([Screenshot: Installation list](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V9coq.png))

---

**Step 1:** I wrote the famous [Hello, World!](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%22Hello,_World!%22_program) program in C++.

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    cout << "Hello, World!" << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

**Step 2:** I clicked on *Build* → *Build Solution*.

**Problem:** ***'stdio.h'**: No such file or directory*. Full Error:

```
1>------ Build started: Project: HelloWorld, Configuration: Debug Win32 ------
1>stdafx.cpp
1>c:\users\dahiana mini\desktop\learncpp\helloworld\helloworld\stdafx.h(10):
    fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'stdio.h': No such file or directory
1>Done building project "HelloWorld.vcxproj" -- FAILED.
========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
```

---

**Troubleshooting details and things I've tried:**

1. *Configuration Properties** → *VC++ Directories*
   `Include Directories  $(VC_IncludePath);$(WindowsSDK_IncludePath);`
2. [Screenshot: Solution Explorer (files in the project)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z1Lgi.png)
3. Code in **stdafx.cpp** file:

   ```
   // stdafx.cpp : source file that includes just the standard includes
   // HelloWorld.pch will be the pre-compiled header
   // stdafx.obj will contain the pre-compiled type information

   #include "stdafx.h"

   // TODO: reference any additional headers you need in STDAFX.H
   // and not in this file
   ```
4. Code in **stdafx.h** file:

   ```
   // stdafx.h : include file for standard system include files,
   // or project specific include files that are used frequently, but
   // are changed infrequently

   #pragma once

   #include "targetver.h"
   #include <stdio.h>
   #include <tchar.h>
   ```

   NOTE: the `#include` for `<stdio.h>` and `<tchar.h>` both have the red squiggle line underneath, and says "cannot open source file".

   Tried: I tried removing the last two lines, but then I got more errors.
5. Tried: Since many suggested that stdafx.h is not required, I tried removing just the first line, `#include "stdafx.h"`. But in order for this to work I had to do a little more. **See the answer below.**

Comment: Well, start by removing the stdafx.h include since it is non-standard and complete *unnecessary* in VS2017.

Comment: Disable precompiled header and remove stdafx*.

Comment: @DeiDei Oh I actually tried that. I'll add it above. In a way this did not work for me, because I only removed that line, `#include "stdafx.h"`. I had to do a little more, which is what I think @manni66 was suggesting. First, I set my options to ignore the precompiled headers by following the instructions [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/y-ignore-precompiled-header-options). Then, I removed that line in the code.  Thanks everyone for their input!

Comment: Either way this is actually a bit weird, as <stdio.h> must exist and work in any correctly configured compiler, even in C++ mode.

Comment: You may want to consider `#include <cstdio>`.

Comment: @PaulStelian if that's the case, perhaps my error was mostly caused by my Windows SDK install not working well with my Visual Studio install. See answer below.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There are three ways to solve this issue.

1. **Ignore Precompiled Headers #1**
   **Steps:** Project > Properties > Configuration Properties > C/C++ > Command Line > in the Additional Options box add /Y-. ([Screenshot of Property Pages](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8rx7U.png)) > Ok > Remove `#include "stdafx.h"`
2. **Ignore Precompiled Headers #2**
   **Steps:** File > New > Project > ... > In the Application Wizard Window click Next > Uncheck the Precompiled Header box > Finish > Remove `#include "stdafx.h"`
3. **Reinstall Visual Studio**
   This also worked for me, because I realized that maybe there was something wrong with my Windows SDK. I was using Windows 10, but with Windows SDK 8.1. You may have this problem as well.
   **Steps:** Open Visual Studio Installer > Click on the three-lined Menu Bar > Uninstall > Restart your computer > Open Visual Studio Installer >  Install what you want, but make sure you install only the latest Windows SDK 10, not multiple ones nor the 8.1.

   The first time I installed Visual Studio, I would get an error stating that I needed to install Windows SDK 8.1. So I did, through Visual Studio Installer's Modify option. Perhaps this was a problem because I was installed it after Visual Studio was already installed, or because I needed SDK 10 instead. Just to be safe I did a complete reinstall.

Comment: The problem with Option #1 is that you have to do this for every project. If I find a better solution, I will post it here.

Answer (score 119):

I got same problem with a project porting from Visual Studio 2013 to Visual Studio 2017.

Fix: change *Properties* → *General* → *Windows SDK Version* to 10

Comment: That worked fo me. Thanks! I would also add that these properties can be reached by right clicking on the project in the solution explorer.

Comment: I also had to install the "Windows Universal CRT SDK" Visual Studio component as described here - https://stackoverflow.com/a/42778079/3893068

Comment: I had the same problem after changing nothing at all in the project. I would assume maybe something to do with windows updates? The version that was selected was 10.something but there was a never one available and that one worked. I assume that this new one used to not be there back when it worked.

Comment: On Microsoft Visual Studio Community 2017 15.7.1 I don't have "Windows SDK Version".  However, right-clicking on solution and doing "Retarget solution" worked.

Comment: LOL, return to `<inherit from parent or project defaults>` save changes, and then return again to `version 10` worked for me

Comment: I was having just a intellisense error. Changed the Win SDK version and it worked, changed it back to the lasted version and still works. Before coding in CUDA you need to debug the coding platform...

Answer (score 21):

Faced the problem of missing `stdlib.h` and `stdio.h` (and maybe more) after installing VS2017 Community on a new computer and migrating a solution from VS2013 to VS2017.

Used [@Maxim Akristiniy](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44754320/274579)'s proposal, but still got error message regarding toolset compatibility. However VS itself suggested to do solution retarget by right-clicking on the solution in **Solution Explorer**, then selecting `Retarget solution` from the menu and the updated `Windows SDK Version` from the drop-down list.

Now my projects build w/o a problem.

Note that you may need to make the project your startup project for the retargeting to catch.

Comment: I've noticed (depressingly) that sometimes one has to exit Visual Studio and restart it after any of this fiddling.

Comment: On Microsoft Visual Studio Community 2017 15.7.1 I don't have "Windows SDK Version" as mentioned in the top-vote-getting answer.  However, your answer worked fine and I didn't have to restart anything.

Answer (score 8):

**For CUDA:**

Right Click on your project.

Go to **Properties->CUDA** and set "**CUDA Toolkit Custom Dir**" to your CUDA toolkit directory.

For me it was: **C:\\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v10.0**

[image]

Answer (score 7):

Just in case you don't want to bump Windows SDK to Windows 10 (you could be for example working on an open source project where the decision isn't yours to make), you can solve this problem in a Windows SDK 8.1 project by navigating `Tools -> Get Tools and Features... -> Individual Compontents tab` and installing the individual components "Windows 8.1 SDK" (under SDKs, libraries and frameworks) and "Windows Universal CRT SDK" (under Compilers, build tools and runtimes):

Comment: I had to install the "Windows Universal CRT SDK" Visual Studio component in addition to changing the Windows SDK Version to 10.

Answer (score 4):

**Scenario:**

1. **Windows 10** with ***Visual Studio 2017*** (FRESH installation).
2. ***'C' project*** (**ERROR** like -> **cannot open source file**: 'stdio.h', 'windows.h', etc.).

**Resolve:**

1. Run '**Visual Studio Installer**'.
2. Click button 'Modify'.
3. Select '**Desktop development with C++**'.
4. From "Installation details"(usually on the right-sidebar) select:

   4.1. **Windows 10 SDK(10.0.17134.0)**.

   - Version of SDK in 4.1. is just for example.
5. Click button 'Modify', to apply changes.
6. Right-click 'SomeProject' -> 'Properties'.
7. 'Configuration:' -> 'All Configurations' and 'Platform:' -> 'All Platforms'.
8. 'Configuration Properties' -> 'General' -> '**Windows SDK Version**':

   - change(select from combobox) SDK version to **currently installed**;
9. Click button 'Apply', to apply changes.

Comment: changing the windows sdk version (step 8) is what helped me.

Answer (score 3):

I faced the same issue. Another solution is to add default includes.

This fixed the problem for me:

```
$(IncludePath);
```

Comment: What's that mean? Please provide some context!

Answer (score 3):

A dirty fix: Add $(VC_IncludePath);$(WindowsSDK_IncludePath); into project Properties / C/C++ / General / Additional include directories

Comment: I.. I'm sitting here legitimately shocked that I had to do this.. I can't believe this worked..

Comment: Why is it dirty?

Comment: Visual Studio should know that these paths have to be included and not ask them from the developer... Perhaps, there is a deeper mistake, but we can fix it in this way...

Answer (score 3):

If you run into this problem with **Visual Studio 2019 (VS2019)**, you can download the build tools from https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/downloads/. And, under Tools for Visual Studio 2019 and download **Build Tools for Visual Studios 2019**.

Answer (score 2):

It was the same issue I was getting.

- Run 'Visual Studio Installer' → *Modify* → *Windows 10 SDK (10.0.17134.0)*.
- Wait for the update to finish.
- Restart your computer.
- Open Visual Studio 2017 and open your project.
- Right click on the project's Solution Explorer.
- Select "Retarget Solution" and then select "Windows 10 SDK(10.0.17134.0)".

It worked for me.

Answer (score 2):

For me the problem was a lack of rights on my Windows account. The following url's helped me to identify the problem:

[stdio.h in Visual Studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35777997/stdio-h-in-visual-studio)

[Microsoft C++ Compiler, Fatal Error C1083: Cannot open include file 'stdio.h'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54184448/microsoft-c-compiler-fatal-error-c1083-cannot-open-include-file-stdio-h)

https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/5402a5ae-82e5-4370-9297-5be12152ce5e/standard-users-cannot-open-windowsh-using-x64-native-tools

Most notably the text "your standard users must have access to registry editing tools if they want to compile win32 projects using Native Tools". I switched user in Windows an logged in with an admin account and the problem was gone.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem after updating my VS2017. Project built fine; but lots of 'errors' when code was brought up in the editor.  Even tried reinstalling VS.  I was able to solve it by setting the option “Ignore Standard Include Paths” to Yes.  Attempted to build the solution with lots of errors.  Went back and set the option to No.  After rebuilding, my problem went away.

Comment: Where do I find that option?

Comment: project properties -> Configuration properties -> C/C++ -> preprocessor -> ignore standard include paths. Yes you're right. Frigging Microsoft b/s again.

Answer (score 0):

Similar problem for me but a little different. I can compile and run the default CUDA 10 code with no problem, but there are a lots of error related to the stdio.h file show in the edit window. Which is annoying.
I solve it by change the code file name from "kernel.cu" to "kernel.cpp". That is wired but works for me. And it runs well so far.

Answer (score 0):

I got this kind of error, too, while trying to open a .cpp file with Vscode. The error persisted even after I re-installed my Vscode like someone suggested above.
What worked for me was:
In your Vscode, after opening the folder that contains your .cpp files, open command palette (ctrl+shift+p), and search for c/c++: "Edit configurations (UI)." Select it.
Scroll down to "compiler path" and paste the path to your gcc compiler (for me, it was: C:\Program Files\CodeBlocks\MinGW\bin\gcc.exe). Note: I installed my gcc compiler through installing CodeBocks IDE.

That's all!

Answer (score -1):

I had the same problem building a Visual Studio 2013 project with the Visual Studio 2017 IDE.

The solution was to set the right "Platformtoolset v120 (Visual Studio 2013). Therefore the Windows SDK 8.1 installed must be installed.
If you want to use Platformtoolset v141 (Visual Studio 2017) there must be Windows SDK 10.

The Platformtoolset can be chosen inside the properties dialog of the project: General * → Platformtoolset