# C:\\Program Files\\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\\VC\\bin\\cl.exe' failed with exit status 2

Tags: python, visual-studio-2012

The below error occurs while installing `pyradiomics` packages using
python setup.py install

> fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'stdlib.h': No such file
>   or directory  error: command 'C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual
>   Studio 14.0\VC\bin\cl.exe'  failed with exit status 2

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Cannot open include file: 'stdio.h' - Visual Studio Community 2017 - C++ Error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44219901/cannot-open-include-file-stdio-h-visual-studio-community-2017-c-error)

Answer (score 0):

This error indicates your compiler can't find the required header files to compile the PyRadiomics C Extensions' source code.

The easiest solution is to get the latest PyRadiomics wheel from PyPi (`pip install pyradiomics`), which are precompiled for 64-bit Python 2.7, 3.4, 3.4, 3.4 on windows, linux and mac.