# Microsoft C++ Compiler, Fatal Error C1083: Cannot open include file 'stdio.h'

Tags: c, visual-studio-2017

I have the following C file.

```
#include <stdio.h>
```

I open an instance of Developer Command Prompt for VS 2017 and type the command.

```
cl [my-file.c]
```

I get the following error message

```
fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'stdio.h': No such file or directory.
```

I am unsure how to resolve this problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The include directories for the current session are stored in the `INCLUDE` environment variable.

You can view this by typing `echo %INCLUDE%` on the command prompt.

To add a directory to the include path, use the command `set INCLUDE=%INCLUDE%;C:\foo\bar`.

The fact, however, that the compiler isn't finding a standard and ubiquitous header like `<stdio.h>` indicates a serious problem with your Visual Studio installation. I would run a repair install if I were you.

Comment: Do you have any idea where VS stores those files?

Comment: @DanGrahn I don't use VS 2017 myself, so nope.

Comment: Thanks. It looks like stdio is missing from that directory.