# Cannot open include file: 'Windows.h': No such file or directory

Tags: c++, winapi, windows-10, visual-studio-2019

Project converted from Visual Studio 2010.

I try to compile it in Visual Studio Community 2019 in Windows 10.

All needed SDK are installed.

All files are exists.

I try to change Windows SDK version, C++ Language standard, C Language Standard and it useless.

Here is my options

[image: Project properties]
[image: Visual C++ directories]
[image: Windows SDK files]
[image: Retarget Project]

All standard headers (cstring, cstdlib, cmath, cassert, algorithm) are not found, but they exists in the specified folders.

What shell I do to compile the project?

Comment: There are no C-include directories in your pictures. What you are showing are the include directories for Windows universal projects. Perhaps you have not chosen "Desktop development"option in the visual studio installer.

Comment: There are all here:

C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.18362.0\um\gl

C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.18362.0\um\

C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.28.29333\include

C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.28.29333\atlmfc\include

C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Auxiliary\VS\include

Comment: @s.m What leads you to assume that those were the include directories for *"Windows universal projects"*?

Comment: I install Visual Studio 2010 and project build fine. I do not know what directories are needed.

Comment: You can refer to [Cannot open include file: 'stdio.h' - Visual Studio Community 2017 - C++ Error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44219901/cannot-open-include-file-stdio-h-visual-studio-community-2017-c-error)