# unable to build native image using quarkus graalvm app

Tags: quarkus, graalvm, graalvm-native-image

I am trying to build a java app with quarkus and graalvm. I am currently using graalvm version ***graalvm-ce-java11-windows-amd64-21.2.0*** and updated the JAVA_HOME, GRAALVM_HOME and system path as well. For MSVC i have downloaded visual studio and selected the option of MSVC during the installation. BUt when I build the application using mvn clean package -Pnative I am getting below error message

```
Error: Error compiling query code (in C:\Users\sujay\AppData\Local\Temp\SVM-3930593782158447217\AMD64LibCHelperDirectives.c). Compiler command ''C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.29.30133\bin\HostX64\x64\cl.exe' /WX /W4 /wd4244 /wd4245 /wd4800 /wd4804 /wd4214 '/FeC:\Users\sujay\AppData\Local\Temp\SVM-3930593782158447217\AMD64LibCHelperDirectives.exe' 'C:\Users\sujay\AppData\Local\Temp\SVM-3930593782158447217\AMD64LibCHelperDirectives.c'' output included error: [AMD64LibCHelperDirectives.c, C:\Users\sujay\AppData\Local\Temp\SVM-3930593782158447217\AMD64LibCHelperDirectives.c(1): fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'stdio.h': No such file or directory]
com.oracle.svm.core.util.UserError$UserException: Error compiling query code (in C:\Users\sujay\AppData\Local\Temp\SVM-3930593782158447217\AMD64LibCHelperDirectives.c). Compiler command ''C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.29.30133\bin\HostX64\x64\cl.exe' /WX /W4 /wd4244 /wd4245 /wd4800 /wd4804 /wd4214 '/FeC:\Users\sujay\AppData\Local\Temp\SVM-3930593782158447217\AMD64LibCHelperDirectives.exe' 'C:\Users\A740125\AppData\Local\Temp\SVM-3930593782158447217\AMD64LibCHelperDirectives.c'' output included error: [AMD64LibCHelperDirectives.c, C:\Users\A740125\AppData\Local\Temp\SVM-3930593782158447217\AMD64LibCHelperDirectives.c(1): fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'stdio.h': No such file or directory]
        at com.oracle.svm.core.util.UserError.abort(UserError.java:139)
        at com.oracle.svm.hosted.c.NativeLibraries.reportErrors(NativeLibraries.java:369)
        at com.oracle.svm.hosted.NativeImageGenerator.processNativeLibraryImports(NativeImageGenerator.java:1616)
        at com.oracle.svm.hosted.NativeImageGenerator.setupNativeLibraries(NativeImageGenerator.java:1090)
        at com.oracle.svm.hosted.NativeImageGenerator.setupNativeImage(NativeImageGenerator.java:907)
        at com.oracle.svm.hosted.NativeImageGenerator.doRun(NativeImageGenerator.java:580)
        at com.oracle.svm.hosted.NativeImageGenerator.lambda$run$2(NativeImageGenerator.java:495)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask$AdaptedRunnableAction.exec(ForkJoinTask.java:1414)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask.doExec(ForkJoinTask.java:295)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool$WorkQueue.topLevelExec(ForkJoinPool.java:1016)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool.scan(ForkJoinPool.java:1665)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool.runWorker(ForkJoinPool.java:1598)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinWorkerThread.run(ForkJoinWorkerThread.java:183)
```

I dont know if the error is because of some version mismatch or wrong library. Please let me know if I am missing anything

Comment: I do not know if this will help, but this [SO questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44219901/cannot-open-include-file-stdio-h-visual-studio-community-2017-c-error) seems to be about the same sort of issue, though not exactly. You may need to set another env variable pointing to the VC runtime

Comment: It seams to more an error in your Graalvm installation

Comment: @PaulStoner: Yes the problem was with Visual Studio installation. Even though I did checked MSVC , I had to install C++ tools to make it work

Comment: @PaulStoner If you can provide your comment as a answer I can approve it..I never thought issue was from VisualStudio's side

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44219901/cannot-open-include-file-stdio-h-visual-studio-community-2017-c-error) seems to be about the same sort of issue, though not exactly. While I do not know if it will help, you may need to set another env variable pointing to the VC runtime